# How can I make a ViewGroup child match_parent when its sibling is GONE?

Tags: android, android-layout, viewgroup

I have a layout whose root `ViewGroup` has two children only one of which is always visible.  The other child's visibility will be set at runtime to `View.GONE` when not applicable.

When both children are visible, the heights are set to `wrap_content` and the layout looks great.  The problem is that I'd like to expand the visible view to `match_parent` when the other is gone.

Is there any way to accomplish this or the equivalent?

Comment: I would suggest you to use ViewGroup as TableLayout then

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, if you want the remaining child view to stretch the full parent's height use Sam's method, if you want the child to eventually fill the parent based on its content size then you don't have to do anything, leave it with `wrap_content`. If this is about your last question, `TableLayout` is a bit problematic(I don't know why I haven't looked very well through its source code), you could probably achieve what you want with another layout.

Comment: @Luksprog, I'm likely going to use the runtime method ala Sam.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change any View's layout like this:

```
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
```

The constructor takes width then height as in: `new LayoutParams(int width, int height)`.
Also there is a LayoutParams class for each type of ViewGroup. Make sure you import the one that refers your particular ViewGroup. So if your ViewGroup is a LinearLayout use:

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;
```

---

> I tried unsuccessfully figuring this strategy out

I'm not certain where you had trouble, but this approach only requires a couple extras lines:

```
// When you want to show both views
view1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
view2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
...

// When you want to hide the second view
view1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

If you hide / show the views multiple times you can save a reference to each LayoutParams object rather than repeatedly creating new objects.

Comment: That's easy; I tried unsuccessfully figuring this strategy out on my own from the API documentation without an example.  I'm pursuing the `TableLayout` approach to see if maybe I don't need to do this programmatically.

Comment: @JeffAxelrod I really doubt that you'll manage to do that by using one of the platform layouts(if you write your own layout that is another story, anyway it would be overkill). An xml layout isn't the place for that conditional logic.

Comment: @Luksprog Hi again!  I assume you recognize that I only want the effect of `fill_parent` and `wrap_content`, not that I need it literally.  I want the view (e.g., a `TextView`) to expand and fill the whole parent when the sibling is set to `GONE` at runtime instead of dividing it `wrap_content`-style with another sibling.  You don't think it's possible with a `TableLayout`?

Comment: @Luksprog your doubts were likely well founded.  I was unsuccessful at coaxing a `TableLayout` row's `EditText` to grow beyond the default size.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried working with `android:layout_weight`?

I put together this small example. Below I added a picture showing both views visible (left) and how it looks like with view2 visibility set to `GONE` (right). As you see, view1 uses up all available space then.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#ff0000" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0000ff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: example]

Comment: This is a great idea, except that it adds the (undesirable) constraint that when both views are showing, that they be split evenly.  As in the original question, I need them to `wrap_content`.

Comment: Well by using different weights you can change the split ratio how you want - e.g. 0.01 and 1 would simulate `wrap_content` for the first view but it would still expand to full screen when the second view is gone.

Comment: Of course, but no matter what weights you choose, it will never adapt to the content of the child view, which is what is implicitly required by the question via the `wrap_content` behavior.